# PHP stream post on news working but picture not uploading

Tags: facebook-graph-api, feed

```
$profile_id = $userInfo['id'];
            $picLocal = "https://xxxxxxxxxx/logo.jpg";
                $attachment = array('access_token' => $decodedSignedRequest['oauth_token'],'message' => $userInfo['name'].' is in the draw to win a Free wine for a year',
             'name' => "Oliver's taringa",
             'link' => $fbconfig['appPageUrl'],
             'description' => 'Oliver\'s Taranga in McLaren Vale is home to the ultra-premium HJ Reserve Shiraz and has supplied grapes for the illustrious Penfolds Grange, arguably the pinnacle of achievement for Shiraz growers in Australia. So join their community to go in the draw to win a years worth of amazing wine!',
             'picture' => $picLocal
                );
                if(!($sendMessage = $facebook->api('/'.$profile_id.'/feed/','post',$attachment))){
                $errors= error_get_last();
                echo "Facebook publish error: ".$errors['type'];
                echo "<br />\n".$errors['message'];
                }
            }
```

before 3 days this code work for all applications. but from last 3 days i see message etc post, only picture we not able to see on news.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n06Jj.jpg

Comment: I'm having the same problem, i'll keep an eye here just in case that anybody post a solution...

Answer (score 0):

the following code is working for me nicely .

```
$data = array(
            "link" => $link,
            "access_token" => $user_access_token,
            "picture" => $image,
            "name"=> $title,
            "description"=> $description
    );


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/".$userId."/feed");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$op = curl_exec($ch);
if (!$op) {
    echo "Curl Error : ".curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}

curl_close($ch);
$res = get_object_vars(json_decode((string)$op));
print_r($res);
```